# valgrind does not show line numbers

Tags: linux, valgrind

I'm probably missing sth obvious. I find many related questions on StackOverflow, but they just tell me things I already did. I compile my test app like:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O0 core_cpu.cpp test.cpp -o test.bin
```

Then, running `valgrind ./test.bin`:

```
...
==23638== Invalid write of size 4
==23638==    at 0x401F12: ??? (in /u/zeyer/setups/combined/2021-05-31/tools/returnn/returnn/extern/WarpRna/warp-rna/test.bin)
==23638==    by 0x40223B: ??? (in /u/zeyer/setups/combined/2021-05-31/tools/returnn/returnn/extern/WarpRna/warp-rna/test.bin)
==23638==    by 0x402AAC: ??? (in /u/zeyer/setups/combined/2021-05-31/tools/returnn/returnn/extern/WarpRna/warp-rna/test.bin)
==23638==    by 0x40361C: ??? (in /u/zeyer/setups/combined/2021-05-31/tools/returnn/returnn/extern/WarpRna/warp-rna/test.bin)
==23638==    by 0x4038B4: ??? (in /u/zeyer/setups/combined/2021-05-31/tools/returnn/returnn/extern/WarpRna/warp-rna/test.bin)
==23638==    by 0x56FB83F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
```

So, there are no line numbers. What am I missing?

**Edit** Ah, I just found the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55780895/133374), which says this was a problem with some older valgrind version, and I actually have an old valgrind version (still Ubuntu 16.04), so that might be it. I'm trying to get a newer valgrind version and test that.

Answer (score 0):

My valgrind version was too old. After installing 3.19.0 (downloading the source and compiling it), it works.